# How set the public IPv6 on my Ubuntu Server 22 on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, ipv6

I'm new to IPv6 stack, still got lot to learn about it.
I got attracted to it when realized I could run my devices NATless and host a small server even with a home router.

When I run `ipconfig` on Windows 11, I get **4** IPv6 on my Wireless adapter

- 2 IPv6 (One seems private and changes along time and another seems  public even changing along time) with my ISP provided ::/64 prefix
- 1 Temporary IPv6 also with my ISP prefix
- 1 Link Local IPv6 which begins with fe80:: (seems one provided by the router used in local nework)

But when I run `ifconfig` or `ip -6 addr` I got **only two** address, one with isp prefix and another starting with fe80

I windows, one of the ipv6 can be reached outiside my network, but I can't do the same in Linux.

How do I configure this?

I tried these tutorials, but unsuccessfully

https://masterdaweb.com/en/blog/configuring-static-ipv6-on-linux/

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-ipv6-networking-configuration/

My adapter stopped to work could not even reach ssh terminal locally, my device has gone of DHCP ipv4 devices list

Answer (score 0):

All addresses that are from your ISP-provided prefix are public addresses. It doesn't matter whether they're fixed or dynamic or whether they change over time, it's the prefix that *makes* them public.

So if `ip addr` shows an address with your ISP prefix, that's all you need. The fact that it has your ISP prefix directly means that the address is "public" in the sense of being globally routable.

Whether it's accessible from outside is most likely a different matter; most likely a firewall on your router. Even though there's no address translation anymore (or indeed *because* of that), there is still a firewall that controls which devices are allowed to be accessed.

(Addresses which keep changing are "priva*cy*" addresses. They're still the same in terms of routeability; their only difference is that they keep changing. You can enable this on Linux if you want, via sysctl.

*Actual* IPv6 private addresses are the ones that start with a `fdXX:`, i.e. ULA addresses. For your current goal, these don't matter at all – as there is no NAT, there is also no interaction between ISP-provided and private addresses, so adding one will not help.)